# Backbone: Hide dialog popup if input has not changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to show a dialog popup if field has the value 0. I'm able to do that, but in render page, if input has the value 0 and is not changed, again I'm seeing that dialog.

Dialog shouldn't be there if input has value 0 on render

```
<input id="input-value" type="text" class="text-controll"/> //this model return values from attributeName from the backend
```

Model on Save:

```
save() {
 if(this.model.get('attributeName') === 0) {
  dialog.confirm(
   "Are you sure you want to save the data"
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: When are you setting the input value to model? when are you calling save? a lot of details are missing here... please see [ask]...

Answer (score 0):

I think Backbone has code to check for this built in:

```
save() {
 var nameChanged = !!this.model.changedAttributes()['attributeName'];

 if(nameChanged && this.model.get('attributeName') === 0) {
  dialog.confirm(
   "Are you sure you want to save the data"
  )
 }
}
```

This could fail if you initialize your Model in some nonstandard way, like creating an empty one and then "changing" to values from your db. But for standard uses, this should work.

Documentation here: https://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes

Comment: I'm achieving the same thing